# Regular Expression For Quoted String

Tags: regex

If I have the following data:

```
"test1"."test2" AND "test1"."test2"
```

What regex can I use to match `"test1"."test2"`?

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
\b"test1"."test2"(\s+|$)
```

In the given example I'd like to match `"test1"."test2"`, and, `"test1"."test2"`

Comment: In what context does that string occur?  Are you trying to extract the text inside the quotes?  As it is, there's not much we can do with the answer.

Comment: What platform are you doing this on? It will affect the Regex notation used. Also can you post the actual code as that may also affect the approach.

Comment: In the given example I'd like to match the whole data.

As long as it works here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

I am fine.

Comment: @Lazarus (reply to deleted answer): Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` matches at a word boundary, i. e. just before or after an alphanumeric character. Since `"` is not alphanumeric (and assuming that there is no word character right before it), the assertion fails - and therefore the entire regex.

Drop the `\b`, escape the dot, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
"test1"\."test2"
```