# A simpler regular expression to parse quoted strings

Tags: javascript, regex

The question is simple. I have a string that contains multiple elements which are embedded in single-quotation marks:

```
var str = "'alice'   'anna marie' 'benjamin' 'christin'     'david' 'muhammad ali'"
```

And I want to parse it so that I have all those names in an array:

```
result = [
 'alice',
 'anna marie',
 'benjamin',
 'christin',
 'david',
 'muhammad ali'
]
```

Currently I'm using this code to do the job:

```
var result = str.match(/\s*'(.*?)'\s*'(.*?)'\s*'(.*?)'\s*'(.*?)'/);
```

But this regular expression is too long and it's not flexible, so if I have more elements in the `str` string, I have to edit the regular expression.

What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this parsing? Performance and felxibility is important in our web application.

I have looked at the following question but they are not my answer:

- [Regular Expression For Quoted String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364041/regular-expression-for-quoted-string)
- [Regular Expression - How To Find Words and Quoted Phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095501/regular-expression-how-to-find-words-and-quoted-phrases)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define the pattern once and use the global `g` flag.

```
var matches = str.match(/'[^']*'/g);
```

If you want the tokens without the single quotes around them, the normal approach would be to use sub-matches in REGEX - however JavaScript doesn't support the capturing of sub-groups when the `g` flag is used. The simplest (though not necessarily most efficient) way around this would be to remove them afterwards, iteratively:

```
if (matches)
    for (var i=0, len=matches.length; i<len; i++)
        matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/'/g, '');
```

[EDIT] - as the other answers say, you could use `split()` instead, but only if you can rely on there always being a space (or some common delimiter) between each token in your string.

Answer (score 2):

## A different approach

I came here needing an approach that could parse a string for quotes and non quotes, preserve the order of quotes and non quotes, then output it with specific tags wrapped around them for React or React Native so I ended up not using the answers here because I wasn't sure how to get them to fit my need then did this instead.

```
function parseQuotes(str) {
  var openQuote = false;
  var parsed = [];
  var quote = '';
  var text = '';
  var openQuote = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var item = str[i];
    if (item === '"' && !openQuote) {
      openQuote = true;
      parsed.push({ type: 'text', value: text });
      text = '';
    }
    else if (item === '"' && openQuote) {
      openQuote = false;
      parsed.push({ type: 'quote', value: quote });
      quote = '';
    }
    else if (openQuote) quote += item;
    else text += item;  
  }

  if (openQuote) parsed.push({ type: 'text', value: '"' + quote });
  else parsed.push({ type: 'text', value: text });

  return parsed;
}
```

That when given this:

```
'Testing this "shhhh" if it "works!" " hahahah!'
```

produces that:

```
[
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": "Testing this "
  },
  {
    "type": "quote",
    "value": "shhhh"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": " if it "
  },
  {
    "type": "quote",
    "value": "works!"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": "\" hahahah!"
  }
]
```

which allows you to easily wrap tags around it depending on what it is.

https://jsfiddle.net/o6seau4e/4/

Answer (score 1):

When a regex object has the the `global` flag set, you can execute it multiple times against a string to find all matches. It works by starting the next search after the last character matched in the last run:

```
var buf = "'abc' 'def' 'ghi'";
var exp = /'(.*?)'/g;
for(var match=exp.exec(buf); match!=null; match=exp.exec(buf)) {
  alert(match[0]);
}
```

Personally, I find it a really good way to parse strings.

**EDIT:** the expression `/'(.*?)'/g` matches any content between single-quote ('), the modifier `*?` is non-greedy and it greatly simplifies the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One way;

```
var str = "'alice' 'benjamin' 'christin' 'david'";
var result = {};

str.replace(/'([^']*)'/g, function(m, p1) {
    result[p1] = "";
});

for (var k in result) {
    alert(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets here and requires more complex string parsing, with both single or double quotes and ability for escaping the quote this is the regex. Tested in JS and Ruby.

```
r = /(['"])((?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*)(\1)/g
str = "'alice'  ddd vvv-12 'an\"na m\\'arie' \"hello ' world\" \"hello \\\" world\" 'david' 'muhammad ali'"
console.log(str.match(r).join("\n"))
  'alice'
  'an"na m\'arie'
  "hello ' world"
  "hello \" world"
  'david'
  'muhammad ali'
```

See that non-quoted strings were not found. If the goal is to also find non-quote words then a small fix will do:

```
r = /(['"])((?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*)(\1)|([^'" ]+)/g
console.log(str.match(r).join("\n"))
  'alice'
  ddd
  vvv-12
  'an"na m\'arie'
  "hello ' world"
  "hello \" world"
  'david'
  'muhammad ali'
```